# How to make query conditional on associated table in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create a query that will return distinct records from one table based on a conditions in an associated table.

Specifically, there is an `Act` model which has_many `Events` and, of course 'Event' belongs_to `Act`  I would like to find those `Acts` that do not have an `Event` on a particular date.

The query needs to be run with a `not` condition because otherwise the results will not exclude any `Act` records.

I have tried a variety of constructions including using merge across class methods but it has not worked.

```
#Act model
def self.busy_on(date)
    joins(:event).merge.not(Event.busy_on(date))
end
```

```
#Event model
def self.busy_on(date)
    where(date: date)
end
```

```
#Controller
Act.busy_on(params[:date])
```

The above is giving me an argument error (expect 1 got 0) but I'm not sure that it's right in the first place.

Comment: You can use a combination of a join & id is null, something like `joins(:event).where(events: { date: data, id: nil })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would recommend going about this.

We will create inverted scopes for busy and available like so

```
class Act < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :events 

   scope :busy_on, ->(date) { joins(:events).where(events: {date: date}) }
   scope :available_on, ->(date) {where.not(id: busy_on(date).select(:id))}
end
```

Here we create one scope for the days that an `Act` is busy and then we use that scope as a counter filter to determine if the act is available. 
The resulting SQL for `busy_on` scope will be:

```
  SELECT 
     acts.* 
  FROM 
     acts
     INNER JOIN events ON acts.id = events.act_id
  WHERE 
     events.date = [THE DATE YOU PASS INTO THE SCOPE]
```

Thus the resulting SQL for the `available_on` scope will be:

```
 SELECT 
   acts.* 
 FROM 
   acts 
 WHERE 
   acts.id NOT IN ( 
      SELECT 
         acts.id
      FROM 
         acts
         INNER JOIN events ON acts.id = events.act_id
      WHERE 
         events.date = [THE DATE YOU PASS INTO THE SCOPE]
   )
```

Comment: Excellent!  A very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the most elegant or 'correct' way to do it but it's the only thing I've been able to make work:

```
#Event model
def self.act_busy_on(date)
    where(date: date).pluck(:act_id)
  end
```

```
#Act model
def self.available_on(date)
    where.not(id: Event.act_busy_on(date))
  end
```

```
#Controller
Act.available_on(params[:date])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Act < ApplicationRecord
  def self.busy_on(date)
    #includes(:events).where(events: {created_at: date, id: nil })
   includes(:events).where("events.created_at = ? AND events.id = ?", date, nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems like it should work. The SQL generated is 'SELECT "acts".* FROM "acts" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."act_id" = "acts"."id" WHERE (events.date = '2019-05-14' AND events.id = NULL)'  But the result is still an empty array.

Comment: joins is an `INNER JOIN` so there will be no events without an `id`

Comment: Now with `includes` you will need to add `references(:events)` or the events table won't be present in the query resulting in a SQL error.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for correct me, as i can see there is a already `has_many :events` association exists, so is there still need of `references(:events)` ?

Comment: @Gabbar yes because `includes` with a string condition will not left join the events table. `includes` will only left join under 2 conditions 1) if you explicitly add `references(:association_name)` 2) If you use a `Hash` where condition (like in your commented code) that references the associated table. Otherwise what includes does is it loads all the records from the main table in the first query and then fires a second query to load the associations based on the ids from the first query

Comment: But now that I am looking at this query it has no hope of working anyway because NULL cannot be used in conjunction with `=` it would be `IS NULL` and secondly you are searching for an `event` where the `id IS NULL` and has a created_at date which is impossible. if the id IS NULL then so is the rest of the row in this join.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to modify `event` to `events` in the joins query.

You asked for `Acts` which are free on a particular date in your question so the query would be like,

```
def get_acts(date)
    includes(:events).where('events.date = ? and events.id = ?', date, nil)
end
```

Now if you call `Act.get_acts(26-05-2019)`, will give you acts which are free on that particular day.